# Extract row numbers to match index R not working

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to retaining the first row of a series using the match feature with R and then applying it to the original data frame so that I only gather the row where the first condition was met.  I'm going to run a calculation and logical test against these duplicated values in new columns but after getting the index of matches correct and then applying them to the original data frame I'm getting a completely mixed up result rather than the first value I should get as contained in its corresponding row.

```
# Extract first row's value

DT1 <- InsiderList3[!duplicated(`Insider CIK`), ]

# Construct Index for Each Grouping (Insider CIK) most recent reported transaction date
index2 <- match(as.character(InsiderList3$`Insider CIK`),as.character(DT1$`Insider CIK`))
dt3 <- InsiderList3[as.numeric(index2),]
```

Here is a sample dput:

```
dput(head(InsiderList3[c('Insider CIK', 'Transaction Date', 'Issuer')], 75))
structure(list(`Insider CIK` = c("0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001009891", "0001012859", 
"0001012859", "0001012859", "0001012859"), `Transaction Date` = structure(c(18358, 
18358, 18101, 18065, 18065, 18039, 17729, 17700, 17674, 17674, 
17345, 17345, 17326, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17014, 
17001, 16964, 16964, 16598, 16590, 16582, 16582, 16409, 16288, 
16288, 16245, 16245, 16217, 16161, 16072, 16052, 15967, 15880, 
15869, 15771, 15710, 15710, 15687, 15603, 15523, 15354, 15354, 
15030, 14979, 14840, 14049, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18358, 18358, 
18358, 18261), class = "Date"), Issuer = c("TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"SANDRIDGE ENERGY INC", "SANDRIDGE ENERGY INC", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "QUEST RESOURCE CORP", "QUEST RESOURCE CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "CHESAPEAKE OILFIELD OPERATING LLC", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "QUEST RESOURCE CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CVR ENERGY INC", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"SANDRIDGE ENERGY INC", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", NA, "NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP", "NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP", 
"NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP", "NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP")), row.names = c(NA, 
75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: My desired output would be a data frame of the exact same dimensions as I started but with just the first row value for each group ID being contained.  Its a large data frame but I'm happy to give you anything you need.  I've never experienced an issue like this with an index.  I've confirmed index vector is a numerical.

Comment: do you need the `match` in the reverses direction

Comment: i.e. `match(as.character(DT1$`Insider CIK`), as.character(InsiderList3$`Insider CIK`) )#
[1]  1 71 72`

Comment: So spot 71 is right in terms of where the next match occurs in the maint table.  In this case it should stay as is but in the way I've done this I get the initial match showing up into row 160 and then it skips over the match at 71 and goes to the next. I cannot see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `first` to get the first value of each column after grouping by `Insider CIK`

```
InsiderList3 %>% 
       group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>%
        mutate_all(first)
# A tibble: 75 x 3
# Groups:   Insider CIK [3]
#   `Insider CIK` `Transaction Date` Issuer                      
#   <chr>         <date>             <chr>                       
# 1 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 2 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 3 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 4 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 5 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 6 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 7 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 8 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 9 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#10 0001008134    2020-04-06         TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# … with 65 more rows
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(InsiderList3)[, .SD[rep(1, .N)], by = .(`Insider CIK`)]
# Insider CIK Transaction Date                       Issuer
# 1:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 2:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 3:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 4:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 5:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 6:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 7:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 8:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 9:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#10:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#11:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#12:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#13:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#14:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#15:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#16:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#17:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#18:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#19:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#20:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#21:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#22:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#23:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#24:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#25:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#26:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#27:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#28:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#29:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#30:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#31:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#32:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#33:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#34:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#35:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#36:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#37:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#38:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#39:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#40:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#41:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#42:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#43:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#44:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#45:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#46:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#47:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#48:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#49:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#50:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#51:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#52:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#53:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#54:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#55:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#56:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#57:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#58:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#59:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#60:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#61:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#62:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#63:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#64:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#65:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#66:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#67:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#68:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#69:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#70:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#71:  0001009891             <NA>                         <NA>
#72:  0001012859       2020-04-06     NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP
#73:  0001012859       2020-04-06     NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP
#74:  0001012859       2020-04-06     NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP
#75:  0001012859       2020-04-06     NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP
```

If the `Insider CIK` is already not ordered, then we create a rowid before getting the first row by group

```
InsiderList3$rid <- seq_len(nrow(InsiderList3))
setDT(InsiderList3)[,  c(list(rid = rid), .SD[rep(1L, .N)]),
   by = .(`Insider CIK`), .SDcols = setdiff(names(InsiderList3), 
      'rid')][order(rid)][, rid := NULL][]
```

---

With the OP's code, it would be the reverse `match` and the replicate those elements

```
idx <- match(as.character(DT1$`Insider CIK`), 
              as.character(InsiderList3$`Insider CIK`) )
out <- InsiderList3[rep(idx, table(InsiderList3$`Insider CIK`)),]
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   Insider CIK Transaction Date                       Issuer
#1   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#2   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#3   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#4   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#5   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#6   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#7   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
#8   0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm able to do that.  The issue comes in creating a new table that matches the original's dimensions but only has the first value in each series rather than all.  I.e. if CIK Number match 1 is in rows 1:70 then I want row 1 duplicated from 1:70. I know this sounds circuitous but I'm going to extract the Transaction Date and Issue columns to bind to the original (that's why I need the index to match) so that I can do calculations relative to last filing date.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've tried and I can't.  Using the the approach I'm left with a data frame that is pretty much identical to the original which I agree is bizarre.

Comment: @js80 do you need `InsiderList3 %>%
    group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>%
    mutate(firstTransactionDate = first(`Transaction Date`))`

Comment: That looks like it works.  I'm sorry this was so difficult.  I greatly appreciate the help.  The whole reason I'm doing this exercise was that I used mutate to capture the first date for each CIK number when it showed up to calculate a time differential between subsequent filings and a logical test and for whatever reason I was only collecting the first date in the entire data frame and not for each subsequent CIK Number. Again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Changing data a bit to show the row id is maintained while creating the second dataset.

Data:

```
InsiderList3$`Insider CIK`[75] <- "0001008134"
```

Code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(InsiderList3)
df2 <- InsiderList3[rowid(`Insider CIK`) == 1, ]
InsiderList4 <- copy(InsiderList3)
InsiderList4[df2, on = c("Insider CIK"), `:=` (`Transaction Date` = `i.Transaction Date`,
                                               Issuer = i.Issuer)]
```

Output:

```
InsiderList4
#   Insider CIK Transaction Date                       Issuer
# 1:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 2:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 3:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 4:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 5:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 6:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 7:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 8:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 9:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 10:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 11:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 12:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 13:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 14:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 15:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 16:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 17:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 18:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 19:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 20:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 21:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 22:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 23:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 24:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 25:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 26:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 27:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 28:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 29:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 30:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 31:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 32:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 33:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 34:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 35:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 36:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 37:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 38:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 39:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 40:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 41:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 42:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 43:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 44:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 45:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 46:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 47:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 48:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 49:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 50:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 51:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 52:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 53:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 54:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 55:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 56:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 57:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 58:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 59:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 60:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 61:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 62:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 63:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 64:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 65:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 66:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 67:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 68:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 69:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 70:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 71:  0001008134       2019-12-31 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# 72:  0001009891             <NA>                           NA
# 73:  0001012859       2020-04-06     NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP
# 74:  0001012859       2020-04-06     NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP
# 75:  0001008134       2020-04-06 TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.
# Insider CIK Transaction Date                       Issuer
```

Comment: Thanks but I think want to match the location where this first row is in the main table and be left with a separate new table of the same dimensions that shows only the first row where there is a corresponding match in the Insider CIK number

Comment: I did not understand your comment. You can get row index by `InsiderList3[, rowid(`Insider CIK`) ]`. Do you have any other data to match with the filterted dataset?

Comment: I want to use one data frame to create two that have the same index.  The first is the complete data frame and then second is just the same dimensions but just the first row's data matching the index and duplicated until the next CIK match comes up.  That's in row 71 of the original.

Comment: Exactly the same as the original.  Only difference is that for example if the first CIK number shows transactions in rows 1-70 the second data frame would just contain the first value for that match in those rows.  Etc etc for the other matches. This way I can bind the two and be confident I'm matched correctly. Thank you.

Comment: See my edit. It should work now. It seems you want to duplicate the first row with other rows in the group.